# Error in calling gmail watch method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail-api, gmail-imap, google-cloud-pubsub

I am calling watch method of gmail to get updates of my mailbox, but it is giving me error

```
Google::Apis::ClientError: invalidArgument: topicName required
```

this is the code

```
service.watch_user('me','projects/devpush/topics/push')
```

can any one please tell me what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and after I consulted the source, I found that you need to build a `WatchRequest` and pass that in to `user_watch`, like so:

```
watch_request = Google::Apis::GmailV1::WatchRequest.new
watch_request.topic_name = 'projects/devpush/topics/push'
service.watch_user('me', watch_request)
```

Comment: This should be marked correct. The third line will also send a response you can save to get the history_id and expiration

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ruby, but maybe you can try giving the topicName as a named parameter?

```
service.watch_user('me', topicName: 'projects/devpush/topics/push')
```

Sorry if I'm wrong, but from the error message, you should add a named parameter.